# haskell combinations with repetition

Tags: haskell

Here is my function that generates all combinations for k items from given set:

```
combR :: [t] -> Int -> [[t]]
combR _ 0 = [ [] ]
combR [] k = []
combR (x:xs) k = combR xs k ++ [x:t | t <- combR xs (k-1) ]
```

However, what it does is, that it only generates combinations without repetition and does not include those, that should repeat, for example for input

`combR [0,1,2] 2`

the output should be `[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1]`

but is only `[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]`

Comment: Your `[x:t | t <- combR xs (k-1) ]` will only generate combinations that start with `x`, since `x :` prepends the `x` to the list `t`.

Comment: When you said "with repetition" I expected that the expected output should also include `[0,0], [1,1], ...` but apparently you only want all the permutations of the non-repeating lists. Perhaps "with repetition" is not the correct term here.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that for a list creates a list of 2-tuples with `x` an element that is "popped" from the list:

```
import Control.Arrow(second)

pickOne :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pickOne [] = []
pickOne (x:xs) = (x, xs) : map (second (x:)) (pickOne xs)
```

This thus gives us:

```
Prelude> pickOne [1,4,2,5]
[(1,[4,2,5]),(4,[1,2,5]),(2,[1,4,5]),(5,[1,4,2])]
```

In each of the 2-tuples, the first element is thus an element we picked from the given list, and the second item is a list of remaining elements.

We can use this in a list comprehension expression where we thus pick one of the elements, and recurse on the list of remaining options:

```
combR :: [t] -> Int -> [[t]]
combR _ 0 = [[]]
combR l k = [ x:xs | (x, rs) <- pickOne l, xs <- combR rs (k-1)]
```

We then can generate combinations with a given number of elements:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> combR [0,1,2] 2
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1]]
Prelude Control.Arrow> combR [1,4,2,5] 2
[[1,4],[1,2],[1,5],[4,1],[4,2],[4,5],[2,1],[2,4],[2,5],[5,1],[5,4],[5,2]]
Prelude Control.Arrow> combR [1,4,2,5] 3
[[1,4,2],[1,4,5],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,5,4],[1,5,2],[4,1,2],[4,1,5],[4,2,1],[4,2,5],[4,5,1],[4,5,2],[2,1,4],[2,1,5],[2,4,1],[2,4,5],[2,5,1],[2,5,4],[5,1,4],[5,1,2],[5,4,1],[5,4,2],[5,2,1],[5,2,4]]
Prelude Control.Arrow> combR [1,4,2,5] 4
[[1,4,2,5],[1,4,5,2],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,5,4],[1,5,4,2],[1,5,2,4],[4,1,2,5],[4,1,5,2],[4,2,1,5],[4,2,5,1],[4,5,1,2],[4,5,2,1],[2,1,4,5],[2,1,5,4],[2,4,1,5],[2,4,5,1],[2,5,1,4],[2,5,4,1],[5,1,4,2],[5,1,2,4],[5,4,1,2],[5,4,2,1],[5,2,1,4],[5,2,4,1]]
Prelude Control.Arrow> combR [1,4,2,5] 1
[[1],[4],[2],[5]]
```